# React Hooks and ActionCable

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, reactjs, actioncable

Trying to get along with React new Hooks and ActionCable, but stuck with the problem that I can't get the right data in Rails when trying to send state.

I've tried to use `send()` method immediately after doing `setState()` and send my updated data, but for some reason, the data which received on the Rails part is old. 
For example, if I put "Example" to the input I'll see "{"data"=>"Exampl"} on the Rails side. I suppose the data update the state later than my request goes.
If I `send()` value from `e.target.value` everything works fine

Therefore I've tried to use new `useEffect()` hook and send data there. But I get only data when rendering the page. Afterward, I don't get anything and sometimes get error `RuntimeError - Unable to find subscription with an identifier`. Seems like effect hook sends data too early or something.

I'm pretty new to Hooks and WebSockets. Would love to get any help here. I can share Rails code, but there is only a receiver and nothing else.

First exmaple:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react"
import ActionCable from 'actioncable'

function Component(props) {
const [data, setData] = useState("");

const cable = ActionCable.createConsumer('ws://localhost:3000/cable');
const sub = cable.subscriptions.create('DataChannel');

const handleChange = (e) => {
 setData(e.target.value)
 sub.send({ data });
}

return (
  <input value={data} onChange={handleChange}/>
 )
}
```

Tried to useEffect and move `send()` there:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    sub.send({ data });
  }, [data]);
```

I'd love to find a way to correctly use React and ActionCable. And use hooks if it's possible.

Answer (score 3):

I was trying an approach similar to Oleg's but I could not `setChannel` inside the action cable create subscription callback. I had to `setChannel` outside of the callback but within the useEffect hook. Below is the solution that worked for me.

1. create consumer in index.js and provide the consumer through Context to App.

```
index.js

import React, { createContext } from 'react'
import actionCable from 'actioncable'
... omitted other imports

const CableApp = {}
CableApp.cable = actionCable.createConsumer('ws://localhost:3000/cable')
export const ActionCableContext = createContext()

ReactDOM.render(
  <Router>
    ... omitted other providers

    <ActionCableContext.Provider value={CableApp.cable}>
        <App />
    </ActionCableContext.Provider>

  </Router>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

2. Use the cable context in your child component and create subscription in useEffect hooks; unsubscribe in clean up

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useContext } from 'react'
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom'

... omitted code

const [channel, setChannel] = useState(null)
const { id } = useParams()

const cable = useContext(ActionCableContext)
useEffect(() => {
  const channel = cable.subscriptions.create(
    {
      channel: 'MessagesChannel',
      id: id,
    },
    {
      received: (data) => {
        receiveMessage(data)
      },
    }
  )

  setChannel(channel)

  return () => {
    channel.unsubscribe()
  }
}, [id])

const sendMessage = (content) => {
  channel.send(content)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can register your cable at root component like that:

```
import actionCable from 'actioncable';

(function() {
  window.CableApp || (window.CableApp = {});
  CableApp.cable = actionCable.createConsumer('ws://localhost:3000/cable')
}).call(this);`
```

so it will be available as global variable;

and then in any component where you want to create channel and send data:

```
const [channel, setChannel] = useState(null);
          useEffect(() => {
         CableApp.cable.subscriptions.create(
          {
            channel: 'YourChannelName',
          },
          {
            initialized() {
              setChannel(this)
            },
          },
        );
      }, []);

return <button onClick={() => channel.send(some_data)} >Send counter</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

```
const handleChange = (e) => {
 setData(e.target.value)
 sub.send({ data });
}
```

setData is like setState in that the state is only updated after the render i.e. after the function has exited. You are sending the current data not the new data. Try this:

```
const handleChange = (e) => {
 const newData = e.target.value;
 setData(newData)
 sub.send({ data: newData });
}
```